# Spotify App API: Add as playlist

Tags: api, spotify

I'm creating a play list dynamically with **m.Playlist()** and then adds tracks with the **.add()** function. But it doesn't seems to work to add those play lists to the toolbar with the **"+ Add as playlist"** button and **sp.core.library.addPlaylist($(this).val());**.

Do you guys have any clue how to save the playlists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create another playlist but with a name `m.Playlist("My Playlist")` and add the specific tracks. The playlist should then appear on the left.

Comment: Ah, awsome! I've beens setting the name with playlist.name = "name". Thank you!