# Spotify app - "Save as Playlist" button

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

I need to add a "Save as Playlist" button to my Spotify app, according to my app feedback from Spotify. I've seen the button in other apps, but as far as I can tell, there is no native implementation of this button - right? SubscribeButton is a button that says "Follow" and isn't right for my case.

I'm trying to implement it myself using Button, but I can't add a playlist to the user's library. The playlists in my app are created using Playlist.createTemporary. Library.publish has no effect. Library.playlists.add has no effect. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spotify App API: Add as playlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522652/spotify-app-api-add-as-playlist)

Comment: That answer is for the old API, I need an answer for the new 1.0 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this does work similar to the old API. Just use `Playlist.Create`, and it will create a new Playlist for the current user. This doesn't really make sense to me.